# Optimization when most entries of the matrix are already fixed?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

The question is to optimize $\min_{\bf{P}}\left\| {{\bf P}^{\text{T}} \bf{AP}}-\bf{B} \right\|_F$ where ${\left\|  \cdot  \right\|_F}$ is the Frobenius norm,  ${\bf{A}},{\bf{B}}$ are any two matrices but $\bf P$ is restricted to be a permutation matrix. A permutation matrix $\bf P$ is a matrix whose every row has a single element being $1$ with all others being $0$, and each row has its $1$ at a distinct column.

> This optimization problem is known as the graph alignment problem if $\bf A$, $\bf B$ are the adjacency matrices of two similar graphs $G_A$,$G_B$. In practice, $A$, $B$ might also very often represent some node features (e.g. the degree of adjacent nodes) of $G_A$ and $G_B$ rather than simply $1$ or $0$ indicating if there is an edge.
>
> To our best knowledge, methods that currently solve this problem all run in  high time complexity, like $O(n^3)$ where $n$ is the number of nodes in the graph.

My question is, if 90% of $\bf P$ are surely 0, e.g. in every row "$1$" might only be placed in about 10% of the positions, but in each row such available positions might be different. In this case, is there any known method to kind of "restrict" the optimization computation to only the 10% flexible positions in the matrix. If there is some, a hint or some reference would be very much appreciated.

> Our attempt: currently the potential strategy we can think of is to permute $\bf P$ so that the fixed zeros are moved together as much as possible, then we might be able to just optimize over "part of" $\bf P$. We are not sure if there is known method already does this.

Comment: You meant that you can't solve the problem with conjugate gradients since you have this constraint that P has to be a permutation.